# Sci-Fi book in which a guy travels a virtual reality world along with friends

Tags: story-identification, books, virtual-worlds

I remember only some of the parts to the book and it will sound kind of weird, but, I really want to figure out what book it was.

Some of the parts I remember are, a guy is in a virtual reality type world, he started traveling with friends, he drowned in “programming” or something, and towards the end he went into a shed and made a big decision.

Comment: Some things that would help, where did you read it, what language was it in, wha years did you read it in and can you remember anything about the cover?

Comment: I know it was probably in 2013’s or older, it was in english, and im lost on the cover

Comment: Could it be Tad William's *Otherland*? It has several characters travelling in various virtual worlds.